# p-dropdown does not display correct label when ngModel variable is an object

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I am using PrimeNG's p-dropdown component. When the page loads initially I am setting the `ng-model` but the drop down shows first element as the selected element always.

**HTML**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"  optionLabel="name" [showClear]="true"></p-dropdown>
<p>Selected City: {{selectedCity ? selectedCity.name : 'none'}}</p>
```

**TS**

```
this.cities = [
            {label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}},
            {label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}},
            {label:'London', value:{id:3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN'}},
            {label:'Istanbul', value:{id:4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'}},
            {label:'Paris', value:{id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}}
        ];
```

Here *New York* is shown as the selected one in the dropdown even if I change the `ng-model` to some other city.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is in `optionLabel="name"` because your city object does not contain a *name* key.

Either you replace it with `optionLabel="label"` or you change your city object from

```
{label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}}
```

to

```
{name:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}}
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4lbz8)